# Monitoring AWS RDS Instances

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, database-performance

I am new to AWS RDS service. Everything is working great, but how can I make sure that my instance is performing well? There are many charts where I can view the performance, but I don't know if the metrics are fine or something needs to be optimized? Right now, I see the following Results:

- **CPU Utilization**: Avg Between 2% & 10%
- **Freeable Memory (MB)**: 700
- **Write IOPS (Count/Second)**: Avg Between 18 & 351
- **Read IOPS (Count/Second)**:  Avg Between 1.9 & 9.9
- **My DB instance class**: db.t2.small Multi-AZ 100 GiB

Any Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

High CPU would mean missing indexes and/or need to reformulate queries.  (2-10% is not 'high'.)

Poor performance, from the user's point of view, could mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable AWS RDS Performance Insights to see greater details about the queries being run and if anything at all needs attention. If you have too many instances running on AWS RDS, it's better to look for some third party monitoring tools like newrelic, grafana, datadog, pganalyze etc.